# Why the limits on the number of users that can be notified in one comment?

Tags: support, comments

Sometimes, it becomes necessary to notify more than one user (using the `@`) in the same comment. However, the current system allows notifying only one user in the same comment.

1. Why this limit?
2. Can we have more?

Comment: Are you aware that the post's author is always notified?

Comment: My guess, it's a single field with the user's UID in the comment record in the database.  No need to make a horribly in-effecient database adding loads of fields that don't usually get used or introducing processing time for record parsing that is almost never used.

Comment: @guntbert: Yes. I may want to notify two users on *my* post very often than not.

Comment: It would be good to have something like this... - @hbdgaf if a user has two post two comments to notify two users, would that be more inefficient? :)